# Cake PHP shows Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, cakephp

Following CakePHP code is in my `index.php` file. When it runs on the server, it shows

> internal server error 500

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}


if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

$vendorPath = ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'lib';
$dispatcher = 'Cake' . DS . 'Console' . DS . 'ShellDispatcher.php';
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH') && file_exists($vendorPath . DS . $dispatcher)) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', $vendorPath);
}

if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
    define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
}
if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
    define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
}

if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/' && file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
        return false;
    }
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);
}

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
        ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
    }
    if (!include 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php') {
        $failed = true;
    }
} else {
    if (!include CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php') {
        $failed = true;
    }
}
if (!empty($failed)) {
    trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
}

App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(
    new CakeRequest(),
    new CakeResponse()
);
```

Comment: Ensure PHP and Apache error logging is enabled and check that. It will provide more information about the issue. I'll bet you haven't enabled the rewrite module.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your app/Config/core.php and change 
Configure::write('debug',0); 
to 
Configure::write('debug',2);

Visit the same page you will get the detail about the error